# How to generate unique date ranges

Tags: scala

I would like to generate unique date range between current date to say like 2050.

```
val start_date = "2017-03-21"
val end_date = "2050-03-21"
```

Not sure how can i create a function for it. Any inputs here please. The difference between the start and end dates can be anything.

Unique date range means the function would never return me a date range which it has already returned.

I have this solution in mind:

```
val start_date = "2017-03-21"

val end_date = "2050-03-21"


while(start_date= "2017-03-21")
{
end_date = start_date+1
return( start_date, end_date)

}

start_date=start_date+1
```

Comment: It is not clear what your goal is. What do you mean by "unique"? What is the expected output? Tell us where you are stuck.

Comment: updated with some information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We will use the `java.time.LocalDate` and `temporal.ChronoUnit` imports to achieve this:

```
scala> import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.LocalDate

scala> import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit

scala> val startDate = LocalDate.parse("2017-03-21")
startDate: java.time.LocalDate = 2017-03-21

scala> val endDate = LocalDate.parse("2050-03-21")
endDate: java.time.LocalDate = 2050-03-21

scala> val dateAmount = 5
dateAmount: Int = 5

scala> val randomDates = List.fill(dateAmount) {
  val randomAmt = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate, endDate) * math.random() // used to generate a random amount of days within given limits
  startDate.plusDays(randomAmt.toInt) // returns a date from that random amount, will not go beyond endDate
}
randomDates: List[java.time.LocalDate] = List(2049-03-16, 2025-12-30, 2042-04-20, 2027-03-14, 2031-03-15)
```

Comment: I get the error as 'Type Mismatch , Expected temporal , Actual : LocalDate'

Comment: I'm not sure why it would be throwing that error. The only method in the code snippet that accepts a Temporal as an argument is the between method (ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(Temporal temporal1Inclusive, Temporal temporal2Exclusive)). 
LocalDate implements the Temporal interface, so it should work. The code above is pasted from the REPL, so it compiled just fine for me. I'm on Java version 8 if that matters.